# Cannot insert row using Flask and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I am doing CS50 project and the current task is to create a register page. User fills in the form and presses button. So it has to be insert into my PostgreSQL database. But when I fill the form and press 'Register' I got this error:

```
StatementError: (sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError) A value is required for bind parameter u'surname' [SQL: u'INSERT INTO users (name, surrname, nickname, password) VALUES (%(name)s, %(surname)s,%(nickname)s, %(password)s'] [parameters: [{':password': u'', ':name': u'John', ':surname': u'Young', ':nickname': u'yolojohny1'}]] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/cd3x)
```

books.py

```
    import os

from flask import Flask, session, render_template, request
from flask_session import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

app = Flask(__name__)

# Check for environment variable
if not os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"):
    raise RuntimeError("DATABASE_URL is not set")

# Configure session to use filesystem
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_URL"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))


@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("register.html")

@app.route('/register', methods=["POST"])
def register():
    "REGISTRATION PROCESS"

    # Get form information
    name = request.form.get("name")
    surname = request.form.get("surname")
    nickname = request.form.get("nickname")
    password = request.form.get("password")


    db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, surrname, nickname, password) VALUES (:name, :surname,"
               ":nickname, :password", {":name": name, ":surname": surname, ":nickname": nickname,
                                        ":password": password})

    db.commit()
    return render_template("success.html")
```

register.html:

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
  New User
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

  <h1>Register new account</h1>

  <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="post">

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="surname" placeholder="Second Name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" name="nickname" placeholder="Nickname">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>

    <div class="formgroup">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Create account!</button>
    </div>

  </form>

{% endblock %}
```

database:

```
  CREATE TABLE "users" (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   surrname VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   nickname VARCHAR NOT NULL,
   password VARCHAR NOT NULL
)
```

What should I do? I googled this Error but nothing helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost there.

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, surrname, nickname, password) VALUES (:name, :surname, :nickname, :password", {":name": name, ":surname": surname, ":nickname": nickname, ":password": password})
```

Firstly, this doesn't execute as you are missing the closing parenthesis after your VALUES list. So to get the statement to execute I had to make it:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, surrname, nickname, password) VALUES (:name, :surname, :nickname, :password)", {":name": name, ":surname": surname, ":nickname": nickname, ":password": password})
```

I imagine that is just a typo translating info into the questions, but nonetheless.

Now, the colon (`:`), prior to the parameter names in your SQL statement is there to tell SQLAlchemy that that name is a bound parameter. [You can read more about it here.](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql). You don't need to include that in the keys of your parameter values `dict`, and that is why you are seeing the error. SQLAlchemy is looking for a parameter named `surname` but that doesn't exist in your supplied parameter values, `:surname` does, but `':surname' != 'surname'` and so no value can be found for the parameter.
This should get you across the line:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, surrname, nickname, password) VALUES (:name, :surname, :nickname, :password)", {"name": name, "surname": surname, "nickname": nickname, "password": password})
```